# Map is almost isomorphism iff tensoring with $\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}} = \mathfrak{m}\otimes_R \mathfrak{m}$ yields isomorphism

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with ideal $\mathfrak m$ satisfying $\mathfrak m^2 = \mathfrak m$, and let $f:M\to N$ be a map of $R$-modules. I want to show that the kernel and cokernel of $f$ are annihilated by $\mathfrak m$ if and only if we get an isomorphism after tensoring with $\widetilde{\mathfrak m} = \mathfrak m\otimes_R \mathfrak m$. Any pointers appreciated! Thanks!

$\textbf{Edit}$: the implications on cokernels in both directions are straightforward using the right exactness of the tensor product; it's the kernels I'm having a bit of trouble with. For example, given that $f\otimes \widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}$ is an isomorphism, to show that $(\ker f)\otimes \mathfrak m = 0$, I would like to compare the Tor exact sequence:$$...\to \widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes \ker f\to \widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes M\xrightarrow{\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes f}\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes \operatorname{im}(f)\to 0 $$ with the short exact sequence $$0 \to \ker(\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes f)\to \widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes M\xrightarrow{\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes f} \widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes N\to 0$$ The issue is that I don't know if the map from $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}, \operatorname{im}(f))$ vanishes...similarly, for the converse, given that $\ker f $ and $\operatorname{coker} f$ are annihilated by $\mathfrak{m}$, to get $\ker(\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes f) = 0$, I would like to compare the same two exact sequences; now the problem seems to be $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}} , \operatorname{coker}(f))$. Perhaps I'm going about this all wrong. Any pointers much appreciated!

Comment: Is your ring commutative or do you have 2-sided ideals?

Comment: Yes, it's commutative.

Comment: Have you found some projective/injzective resolution using the property $m^2 = 0$?

Comment: yeah would like to get a projective/flat resolution of $\mathfrak{m}$ probably but not sure how to do this...(I assume you mean $\mathfrak{m}^2 = \mathfrak{m}$).

Comment: I would say it would be interesting to compute this derived functor in the derives category of module complexes, using a bar resolution of $m$ to get a nice chain complex

Comment: Hmmm—can you offer any pointers for how to carry this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\widetilde{f}=1_{\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}}\otimes f.$

The converse direction is quite easy, and works just as well for $\mathfrak m$ as $\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}.$

Assume $\widetilde{f}$ is an isomorphism.
Consider an arbitrary $x\in\ker f$ and $m\in\mathfrak{m}.$
We want to show that $mx=0.$ (For the cokernel we can just use right exactness, as you mention.)
Write $m$ as a finite sum $\sum a_ib_i$ with $a_i,b_i\in\mathfrak{m}.$
Define $x'=\sum a_i\otimes b_i\otimes x\in \widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes M.$
Then $\widetilde{f}(x')=\sum a_i\otimes b_i\otimes f(x)=0$ because $x\in\ker f.$
Since $\widetilde{f}$ is an isomorphism, $x'$ is zero.
Let $\mu$ be the multiplication map $\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes M\to M$
(defined on simple tensors by $\mu(a\otimes b\otimes y)=aby$).
Then $mx=\mu(x')=\mu(0)=0.$

For the forward direction, assume that $\mathfrak{m}$ annihilates $\ker f$ and $\operatorname{coker} f.$

First step: reduce to the case that $f$ is injective.
To do this, factorize $f$ as $M\to M/\ker f \to N.$
Observe that $\mathfrak{m}\otimes \ker f$ is zero: it's generated by simple tensors $a\otimes x$ with $a\in\mathfrak m$ and $x\in\ker f,$ and by picking a decomposition $a=\sum a_ib_i\otimes x$ with $a_i,b_i\in\mathfrak m$ we get $a\otimes x=\sum a_i\otimes b_ix=0.$
So $\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes \ker f$ is also zero.
Since $\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes -$ is right exact, it sends $M\to M/\ker f$ to an isomorphism.
So we just need to prove that it sends the image map $M/\ker f\to N$ to an isomorphism.
From here on, let $f$ denote this image map. Note this doesn't change the cokernel.

Let's try to define an inverse
$$g:\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes N\to \widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes M$$
to $\widetilde{f}.$
We will do this by defining a multilinear function
$G:\mathfrak m\times\mathfrak m\times N \to \widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes M,$

For $y\in N$ and $m\in\mathfrak m$ let $f^{-1}(my)$ denote the unique element $x\in M$ such that $f(x)=my,$ which
exists by the assumption that $m$ annihilates $\operatorname{coker} f.$
To define $G(a,b,y)$ pick a decomposition $a=\sum_i a_ia'_i$ with $a_i,a'_i\in\mathfrak{m},$
and set $G(a,b,y)=\sum_i (a_i\otimes b\otimes f^{-1}(a'_iy)).$

To see that $G$ doesn't depend on the choice of decomposition of $a,$ consider a decomposition $b=\sum b_jb'_j$ with $b_j,b'_j\in\mathfrak m.$ The condition on $x$ is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
x&=\sum_{i,j} (a_i\otimes b_j\otimes b'_jf^{-1}(a'_ix))\\
&=\sum_{i,j} (a_i\otimes b_j\otimes a'_if^{-1}(b'_jx))\\
&=\sum_j (a\otimes b_j\otimes f^{-1}(b'_jx))
\end{align*}
which is independent of the decomposition of $a.$

Define $g$ by $g(a\otimes b\otimes y)=G(a,b,y).$ There are a few things to check but I think they are all easy from here:

- $G$ is indeed $R$-linear in each of $a,$ $b,$ and $y$
- $\widetilde{f}(G(a,b,y))=a\otimes b\otimes y$
- $g(\widetilde{f}(a\otimes b\otimes x))=a\otimes b\otimes x.$

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer already, but would like mine be checked.

###### preparation

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0@>>> \mathfrak{m}@>>>R@>>>R/\mathfrak{m}@>>>0\\
@.@.@.@.\\
@. \widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}@>i>>\mathfrak{m}\approx\mathfrak{m}\otimes R@>q>>\mathfrak{m}\otimes R/\mathfrak{m}@>>>0\\
@.@.@.@.\\
@. \widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes L@>i'>>\mathfrak{m}\otimes L@>q'>>\mathfrak{m}\otimes R/\mathfrak{m}\otimes L@>>>0
\end{CD}
$$
As $i$ is surjective (using assumption and canonical isomorphism $\mathfrak{m}\approx\mathfrak{m}\otimes R$), $q$ is zero. $i'$ is surjective (right-exact tensoring) and $q'$ is zero.

> If $\mathfrak{m}L = 0,$ then
> $$
>   \mathfrak{m}\otimes R/\mathfrak{m}\otimes L = 
> \mathfrak{m}\otimes (L/\mathfrak{m}L) = \mathfrak{m}\otimes L
> $$
> and $q'$ is isomorphism, finally $\boxed{\mathfrak{m}\otimes L=0}.$

###### $\ker$ case

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
@. \widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes \ker f@>g'>>\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes M@>G'>>\widetilde{\mathfrak{m}}\otimes N@>>>0\\
@.@V{V'}VV@V{V=m' \otimes m \otimes x\mapsto m'm\otimes x}VV@VVV\\
@. \mathfrak{m}\otimes \ker f@>g>>\mathfrak{m}\otimes M@>G>>\mathfrak{m}\otimes N@>>>0\\
@.@V{U'}VV@V{U=m \otimes x\mapsto mx}VV@VVV\\
0@>>>\ker f@>>>M@>>>N@>>>0
\end{CD}
$$
All rows are exact. Using assumption on $\mathfrak{m},$ one sees that $V', V$ are surjective.

Assume $G'$ is isomorphism. Then map $g'=0,$ $0 = U\circ V \circ g' =  U'\circ V'.$ As $$\operatorname{im}U'= \operatorname{im}U'\circ V' = 0,$$ obtained $U'=0.$ Assuming $G$ is isomorphism is easier.

The other direction. Apply note above to $\ker f,$ so $g'=g=0.$

###### $\operatorname{coker}$ case

Omitted.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post a summary of Colin's solution, with fewer elements and more diagrams in the flavour of dsh's partial solution. Please correct me if I've gone wrong somewhere.
$\newcommand{\on}{\operatorname}
\newcommand{\coker}{\on{coker}}
\newcommand{\im}{\on{im}}
\newcommand{\m}{\mathfrak m}
\newcommand{\mt}{\widetilde {\m} }
\require{tikzcd}$

We want to prove the following are equivalent:
(1): $f\otimes \mt$ is an isomorphism.
(2): $\ker(f)\otimes \m = \coker(f)\otimes \m =0$

[image: page1]

[image: page2]